# Tomato Plants wilting

Tags: diseases, tomatoes

[image: Whats wrong with my tomato plant? The up clo se one is a Celebrity Hybrid Cherry tomato, and the one in the back is a Cherokee Tomato]

Whats wrong with my tomato plant? The up close one is a Celebrity Hybrid Cherry tomato, and the one in the back is a Cherokee Tomato from “Bonnie plants.”
I sprayed them with miracle grow All Purpose plant food. Here in New England nights do get down to mid 40s Fahrenheit.

Comment: How long did you harden them off before putting them in full sun?

Comment: does it have enough nitrogen?

Comment: @jurp I hardened them for at least 4 days, no more than 8 days.

Comment: @black thumb they are in Miracle grow potting mix and I fed them the MG all purpose plant food. The Food doesn’t have nitrogen content besides(urea) and the the potting mix does not specify a nitrogen weight like traditional fertilizers.